# Button to appear or disappear based on checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a column in a table that contains checkboxes so that the user can click multiple rows and delete the data.  I have managed to make a delete button appear when the boxes are clicked by using a for loop.  What I am struggling with is how to make the button disappear when the user un-checks all the boxes. I have banged my head against the wall for longer than I'd like to admit and I haven't found any previous questions that have been helpful. Thanks in advance for any input!

```
function memDeleteButton() {
    // Pass the checkbox name to the function
    let checkboxes = $('input[name=members]:checked');
    let deleteButton = document.getElementById("memDeleteSelected");

    // loop over all of the checkboxes
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

        if (checkboxes[i].checked = true) {
            deleteButton.style.display = "inline";

        }
        else if (checkboxes[i].checked = false) {
            deleteButton.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query selector `'input[name=members]:checked'` selects only **checked** checkboxes so the _if statement_ that checks again if it is checked doesn't make sense.

Comment: `if (checkboxes[i].checked = true) {` looks like a bug. This is an assignment statement and is always true. Please use `===` to do comparisons and use avoid the `if (condition === true)` pattern unless you really mean to prohibit all truthy outcomes other than exactly `true`. `if (condition)` is much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let checkboxes = $('input[name=members]:checked');`

You are selecting only check boxes that are checked here.

`document.getElementById("memDeleteSelected");`

If you are using JQuery then why not stay consistent.

`checkboxes[i].checked = true`

Your checking the checkbox with this statement. `=` this the assignment operator. you can use equality operator `===` here.

`checkboxes[i].checked` returns a boolean so you can remove the equality operator because this will either be true or false.

```
function memDeleteButton() {
  let checkboxes = $('input[name=members]'),
    deleteButton = $('#memDeleteSelected');

  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      deleteButton.show();
    } else if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
      deleteButton.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ggorlen I was going to add the explanation :)

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.  I think it's painfully clear how new I am and I appreciate your help.